# How to bake "full render" in blender

Tags: uv, baking, texture-baking

My objective is to make models for android so I want to bake textures on low poly (plane) in case of a high poly floppy disk. I want the textures to appear on both sides of the plane. I tried "Full render but all in vain".

EDIT: This is because I did not check "Selected To Active"

When I did a full render bake, this is what I got
[image: Full render bake]

Could you enlist steps to do this??

Secondly if instead of a plane, i make a cuboid and I want textures to appear on all sides of the cuboid as if someone take picture and apply on the faces of the cuboid. How is that possible??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select the high poly then the low poly mesh. So the active will be the low poly. Check the option *Selected to Active* in the *Bake* panel. Here is an example:

[image: Example]

To be able to do this you have to UV unwrap the plane or cuboid and assign
a texture for the UV to bake on. But you have already done this. :) To use
a cubeoid, you simply have to adjust it so that it represents the models
geometry as close as possible.

Comment: How should bake the other side as well??
Suppose I want to bake the other side of the floppy?

Comment: In case the plane is at the same position as the high poly model, it will be probably ok simply to Flip the normals (3D view > mesh tools (toggle it with T) > Flip Direction). But you cannot use two textures for the two sides when developing games. You will have to use two planes, with opposite normals. Generally I think a cuboid would be a better idea to use.

Comment: Usually when developing games nowdays you can use shaders, so you should bake normals, ambient occlusion and texture, and use those for the material setup in the game engine.